# what is the purpose of Specific line in the Code

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, windows-console

i am reading a book named **"Visual C# 2012 Programming"**  and i came up with following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ch05StringManupulationEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myString = "String with small s";
           char[] myChar = myString.ToCharArray();

            foreach (char whatever in myString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", whatever);                
            }
            Console.Write("\nyou have entered {0} characters in String ",myString.Length);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know what the aurthor is doing on line :
  **`char[] myChar = myString.ToCharArray();`**
because he is not using the variable named **myChar** anywhere in the code and even though i commented the line and compiled the program the output is same, can any one explain what is the purpose of this line in this code ?

Comment: If it is not used - no purpose. You should mail authors of the book if you think there is some hidden value of that line.

Comment: My guess is that it was left over from an old version of the code. It's all too easy for book listings to get out of date :(

Comment: Or may be this class is also used somewhere else in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably they forgot to remove that line or show what does it do, It's an array of character, A string is full of characters, each letter of a string is a character, you can access any of these arrays by using a zero based numbers, for example:

```
string a = "Hello";

// Prints e
Console.WriteLine(a[2]);
```

You can change this line to myChar to understand, It's same to an array of string, Which means a string is an array of chars, here's the example:

```
foreach (char whatever in myChar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", whatever);                
}
```